# Using variables in HTML

Tags: html, json

I'm looking for a way to use variables in my website. 
I want something link this.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>This product cost</h2> {{product_price}}
</div>
```

I've tried to use angular with the data in json-file, but that was too hard to understand for me. I can create a json-file from the article database with the prices in it.

Question is:
What is a **simple** way to just grab a piece of data (price in this case) from a file (json or any what is simple) and display it on my webpage (HTML)

Comment: You will need a data source on your server and some way to substitute the data values into the placeholders. There are thousands of ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a static markup language. It is not a programming or scripting language. To accomplish your goal, some sort of server-side scripting needs to be done. This means your server needs to run an application which compiles some code and generates resulting static HTML which will then be served to the browser each time an HTTP request is made. There are many server-side scripting options available. The most popular is PHP, but almost every major desktop programming language has tools available to let it be used as a server side HTTP preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for templates:

I would suggest : [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [mustache](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) but you can google others.

For handlebars other than their docs here is a nice [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-handlebars--net-27761)

#### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdiamond/7j3852r9/1/)

```
<script id="Handlebars-Template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>This product cost {{product_price}}</h2> 
  </div>
</script>

<script>
   // you'll need to require jquery
  data = {"product_price": "5,00$"} 
  var source   = $("#Handlebars-Template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

$('body').append(template(data));
</script>
```

Comment: I upvoted but took my vote back. You need to post an example; answers with just links aren't really answers

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting to **bind** data. And you can achieve this with *moustache* **http://mustache.github.io/**

Comment: The OP said they saw angular, but thought it was too complicated

Answer (score 0):

The right way to use tokens like that is on the back end or with a front-end MVC like Angular. Barring that, don't use tokens. Use JS insertion, like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>This product cost</h2> <span id="myId"></span>
</div>

<script>
var myVar = whateverFromMyJsonFile;
document.getElementById('myId').innerHtml(myVar);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/eja0hycz/

```
var tpl = _.template( '<div class="container"><h2>This product cost</h2> <%= product_price %></div>');
document.body.innerHTML = tpl({product_price: 25})
```

Or you can use a script tag so you don't have HTML in a JavaScript string http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/eja0hycz/1/

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>This product cost</h2> <%= product_price %>
  </div>
</script>

var tpl2 = _.template(document.getElementById('tpl').innerHTML);
document.body.innerHTML = tpl2({product_price: 25});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with just HTML, you will need (at least) some kind of client-side scripting language as Javascript.

You mentioned you tried with Angular, but that was too cumbersome for you.
Let's then try to make a simple example using [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/):

here's how it could be:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <script type="text/template" id="container-template">
    <div class='container'>
      <h2>This product cost</h2> {{product_price}}
    </div>
  </script>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var source = document.getElementById('container-template').innerHTML.trim();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    var data = {product_price: 25};
    document.body.innerHTML = template(data);

      // Would render:
      //
      // <div class="container"><h2>This product cost</h2> 25</div>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```